# ArcGIS js API create map layer from shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a couple of shapefiles that i'd like to display in a map that i've created with the ArcGIS js API. I tried creating a service from ArcGIS server but ran into "ArcGIS cannot access the data file." Is there any other way i can create a layer from a shapefile?

Answer (score 2):

You can't read a shapefile directly from an ArcGIS js application, you must publish the shapefile through ArcGIS Server.

If ArcGIS cannot access the file maybe it's just a permission issue on the files. You should grant read permission to the ArcGISSOC (10.0) or arcgis (10.1, 10.2) account. If you are using an ArcGIS Server > 10.1 you must also register the directory.

You may take a look [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01540000039r000000) (applies to version 10.2)

Comment: I've given full control permissions to the files but i'm still getting the error for some reason

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS Server are you using? How the shapefile is referred in the MXD?

Comment: 10.2.1
I created a folder connection to the shapefile folder, dragged the shapefile to a map and I'm trying to share the map as a service. When publishing as a service it requires that i register the folder to the data store. I'm using "\\servername\Data\Shapefiles" as the publisher folder path. I can see that the arcgis account has access to all t he files but i still get "The ArcGIS Server is not able to connect to the specified directory. Please ensure the folder exists and has the appropiate permissions for the ArcGIS Server to access it."

Comment: 1) check that inside the MXD you're pointing to the UNC path and not the local path. Click DX on the layer -> Source tab

Comment: 2) you must give sharing permission to the arcgis user, not file permission only (there are two types of permissions on windows)

Comment: Checked everything, it seems to have the right permissions but i'm still getting the error. Not sure what else i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Go to the ArcGIS Server administration web interface in SIte->Data store and check that your folder is accessible from ArcGIS Server